# How to write a jQuery plugin compatible with Webpack Encore

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, webpack-encore

I've a small, custom jQuery plugin:

```
(function ($) {

    $.StandardForm = function (element) {
        
        // ...
    };

    $.StandardForm.prototype = {

        submit: function(onDone, onError, always) {
        
            // ...

            $.ajax({

               // ...   
            })
        },


        startSubmit: function() {

            // ...
        },

    // ..
    };

}(jQuery));
```

Now I'm trying to modify to to be used with Webpack Encore. I want to do it the proper way, neither with `global.$ = $;` nor with `.autoProvidejQuery()`.

I tried to modify it like this:

```
import $ from "jquery";
(function ($) {

    $.StandardForm = function (element) {
        
        // ...
    };

    $.StandardForm.prototype = {

        submit: function(onDone, onError, always) {
        
            // ...

            $.ajax({

               // ...   
            })
        },


        startSubmit: function() {

            // ...
        },

    // ..
    };

}(jQuery));
```

The first `$` is ok, but then it fails on the final `}(jQuery));`:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Yes, it's obvious "why", but I don't know what's the right syntax to import jQuery and alias it to `$` too.

I tried:

```
import $ from "jquery";
import jQuery from "jquery";
```

But it explodes.

Any hint?